# find alphabatic series value of ABC & ACA

Tags: php, laravel

suppose if the value of A = 1 , B = 2 ----- Z = 26 and now AA = 27 , AB = 28, so now find what will the value of ABC and ACA etc.

Please help me to make this program in php.

Comment: We are happy to help, but the idea is that you would make some effort yourself and we can help solve any problems.

Comment: Actually this is just a series which value will be increment by one from it's last value. for example A= 1 , B=2, ------ Z=29, AA=27, There is no concept of adding value. @Nick

Comment: Think of it as an Excel sheet, and you count the columns

Comment: first time loop is run with one alphabet A= 1 -----Z= 26 , then again loop will be start with two alphabet and it's value will increment by 1 with the last alphabet and then process will be continued  till all series will not completed.

Comment: what is the expected value of ABC & ACA?

Answer (score 6):

Using a `for` loop over each character of the input string.  Then using the `ord()` function to fetch the ASCII code of the character - as A is 65 and A is supposed to be 1, adjust it by 64.  At each stage multiplying the previous value by 26 to account for the new *digit*.

```
$input = "A";

$index = 0;
$input = strtoupper($input);
for( $i = 0, $end = strlen($input); $i < $end; $i++ )   {
    $index = ($index*26)+(ord($input[$i])-64);
}
echo $index;
```

For `A` it gives `1`, for `AB` it gives `28`.

Added the line

```
$input = strtoupper($input);
```

as lower case letters should be properly adjusted.

Comment: Definitely deserves more than the single upvote I can give!

Comment: Not sure this works when we get to `ABC`, it should return `731`, but it returns `23227`

Comment: @JustCarty - not sure - I've just tried it and it does return 731.

Comment: Just to check, Because it's early and I'm tired. For multiple chars, is the ($index*26) actually accounting for the previous char?

Comment: @Jonnix Same as when in decimal you multiply the value by 10 when you add an extra digit to the end.  For base 26 (the alphabet) you * by 26

Comment: I guess it's a play on the old saying "It _doesn't_ work on my machine"...

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised it's because I used `abc` instead of `ABC`; so I am a liar. +1 for a great solution.

Comment: @JustCarty, actually you have a good point and I've updated my answer to force it to upper case before processing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function abc($string){
    $array = array('A'=>1,'B'=>2,'C'=>3,'D'=>4,"E"=>5,'F'=>6,'G'=>7,'H'=>8,'I'=>9,'J'=>10,'K'=>11,'L'=>12,'M'=>13,'N'=>14,'O'=>15,'P'=>16,'Q'=>17,'R'=>18,'S'=>19,'T'=>20,'U'=>21,'V'=>22,'W'=>23,'X'=>24,'Y'=>25,'Z'=>26);  
    $string = strtoupper($string);
    $defautStart = 0;
    $count = strlen($string);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $defautStart = ($defautStart * count($array)) + $array[$string[$i]];
    }
    return $defautStart;
}

$string = 'ABC';
$value  = abc($tring);

echo $value;
```

Comment: bro , I know you need reputation but stop copying others answer, you copy mine same to same, word to word time to give you downvote :p so you realize, I deleted my answer because the user already gets his answer.